# Displaying dynamic image when image field is empty

Tags: views, media

I need to implement the following functionality in Drupal 7

I'm implementing a view to display a list of spare parts . A spare part has a category(oil pump, engine, etc...) assigned.

When the image of the spare part is empty , need to show the image of the category.

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: its simple.  add default image to image field

Answer (score 1):

In your view, set first a field to show the image of the term. **hide it.** Now set the field image of your node, and "rewrite result if field is empty" with the **token** of your first field.

Have fun.